# 'Run a program' option in windows service pannel for failure recovery

Tags: windows, windows-services, recovery

I am trying to run a perl script whenever there is a service crash. The perl script intends to restart the service and send a mail to all the developers.

I have used windows recovery options for that, where it has an option to **run a program** . I have filled the required details in the command line option but the script doesn't seem to get executed. Can you please help me by sharing your knowledge on this?

[Recovery tab configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSIl6.png)

I have tried with Restart service option and that is working fine but the run a program isn't executing the script. Am I missing something? 
Any comment on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented a recovery option to run a powershell script that attempts to restart the service a defined number of times and sends an email notification at the conclusion, it also attaches a txt file with recent relevant logs.

After several attempts (and despite all the other things I have seen) The configuration of fields on the recovery tab in services is as follows:

Program: Powershell.exe
   **Not C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe

Command line parameters: -command "& {SomePath\YourScript.ps1 '$args[0]' '$args[1]' '$args[n]'}"

eg: -command "& {C:\PowershellScripts\ServicesRecovery.ps1 'Service Name'}"

**The $args are parameters that will be passed to your script. These are not required.

here is the powershell script:

```
cd $PSScriptRoot

$n = $args[0]

function CreateLogFile {
$events = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SomeSource -Newest 40
if (!(Test-Path "c:\temp")) {
    New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -Type directory}
if (!(Test-Path "c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt")) {
    New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -Type File -Name "ServicesLogs.txt"}
    $events | Out-File -width 600 c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt
}

function SendEmail  {
$EmailServer = "SMTP Server"
$ToAddress = "Name@domain.com"
$FromAddress = "Name@domain.com"

CreateLogFile

$Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
send-mailmessage -SmtpServer $EmailServer -Priority High -To $ToAddress -From $FromAddress -Subject "$n Service failure" `
-Body "The $n service on server $env:COMPUTERNAME has stopped and was unable to be restarted after $Retrycount attempts." -Attachments c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt

Remove-Item "c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt"
}

function SendEmailFail  {
$EmailServer = "SMTP Server"
$ToAddress = "Name@domain.com"
$FromAddress = "Name@domain.com"

CreateLogFile

$Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
send-mailmessage -SmtpServer $EmailServer -Priority High -To $ToAddress -From $FromAddress -Subject "$n Service Restarted" `
-Body "The $n service on server $env:COMPUTERNAME stopped and was successfully restarted after $Retrycount attempts. The relevant system logs are attached." -Attachments c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt

Remove-Item "c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt"
}

function StartService {

$Stoploop = $false

do {
   if ($Retrycount -gt 3){
     $Stoploop = $true
     SendEmail
     Break
    }

   $i =  Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -imatch $n} | select Name, State, StartMode
    if ($i.State -ne "Running" -and $i.StartMode -ne "Disabled") {

        sc.exe start $n
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 35

        $i =  Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -imatch $n} | select State
          if ($i.state -eq "Running"){
              $Stoploop = $true
              SendEmailFail}
          else {$Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1}
    }        
}
While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
}

[int]$Retrycount = "0"
StartService
```